# How to get multple words in a search with Lucene 4

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I'm trying to get a string with Lucene 4. Actually now I'm using SpanTermQuery , but it only is able to get simple words like "Walking", "dog" ..etc. But what I want to do is get more complex as "The dog is walking".

Is there any kind of query which does that?

Answer (score 0):

The "get multiple words" concept is very generic. If you mean that you'd like to get a phrase like "the dog is walking" then you can use A [SpanNearQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html) specifying slop and in order where:

- slop Is the maximum number of intervening unmatched positions permitted;
- inorder specifies if the matches have to be in order.